# Is it my responsibility to refute misinformation in social situations?

Tags: etiquette, communication, community

Seldom does a day pass without a juicy piece of misinformation catching my eye. Generally these are the regular thoroughly debunked myths. Be it that vaccines cause autism, or humans cannot possibly influence the climate system since 'we're so small compared to the Sun'. Sure, I utter to myself after a four pi-radian eyeroll.

Is that all I should be doing?

> **Voices in my head**
>
> - A second-year chemistry student hardly possesses sufficient experience in climatology or immunology.
> - But established *basic* scientific facts do not need a PhD to communicate. After all, science is not about arguments from authority. Rather it bases upon peer-reviewed research published in reputable journals. As far as I restrict myself to citable argumentation, I should be fine.
> - Good luck with that! This individual has already made up their mind. Any mention of a myth will have them in a defensive position, ready to turn on caps lock. Then you will only reinforce the erroneous beliefs you set out to disprove.
> - Fine, I shall not proceed.
>
> (repeat)

Ultimately, these are my friends. Former training buddies, in some cases relatives, or even an occasional lecturer. Sitting idly has not worked once. If anything, one myth seems to build on the other. A guy who thought Coca-Cola Zero contained no calories now shares blogs which propose that smoking is beneficial. Not a true story (yet) but you get the idea.

Is it my responsibility as a student of science to embark on this quest? Or is the exercise in vain, at best up to representatives of the corresponding fields of study?

By the way, there is no evidence that the Earth is round... (Yes, a bad joke I left for last.)

Comment: Indeed, there is a good bit of evidence that the Earth is not round at all!

Comment: Yes, earth is not a round sphere, but flattened at the poles...

Comment: This question is probably too open-ended and opinion-based to belong on this site unfortunately, even though I think it's a good question to discuss and debate. My personal view is that yes, as a knowledged member of society you have some responsibility to inform others. However, I don't think that is the same as a responsibility that others are informed - people might have many reasons not to listen to scientific wisdom, and some can be convinced and some cannot. It's up to the individual to decide what the limits are on their time and patience.

Comment: @BryanKrause Agreed. I did spend time reading and browsing various .SE sites. Academia seemed best but not perfectly suited. As for your personal view, it conforms with my own. Open to hear other ideas as well, and you should probably write up a short answer if you have the time!

Comment: Oh, and just so we are on the same page. Certainly I affirm numerous ideas which do not hold up to scrutiny. Though initially difficult, if this is demostrated, I view it as a growing experience. Something to be grateful for. Thus in the spirit of *treat others as you wish to be treated* I should be more active.

Comment: Is this not just over the borderline of being off-topic?

Comment: You can't save everyone from ignorance. There will always be ignorami. :)

Comment: The only thing that is round in this world is the soccer ball! ;-)

Comment: @101010111100 +1 for introducing me to a new plural form. Wish I could use it in Estonian (native language). Massimo Ortolano, thank you for the *down to earth* analogy ;)

Comment: I don't understand in what way sitting idly has not worked for you.  I haven't understood what you've done in these situations, and in what way it hasn't worked for you. // As you progress academically, you will probably find yourself facing this problem less and less often.  Of course your family will not go away.  So they're the ones you really need to think about.  How to preserve your relationships as you get farther and farther apart intellectually.  My advice there is to take the time periodically to talk to family members about what you're excited about from your studies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with academia.

Comment: @RoboKaren Wouldn't go as far as to state the topic has *nothing* to do with academia. It does somewhat relate to the life of a (graduate) student and expectations to an academian, even pedagogy. Perhaps that is because that is what I wished to find ;). In the end I agree with the closing. As a last straw, do you think it could be reworded or mitigated somewhere more suitable? (Final argument to support some other action: how are posts like [these](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80227/will-a-phd-help-me-as-a-startup-founder) more on-topic considering the do-not-ask @ Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should say more, but definitely don't respond all the time, and definitely don't be too harsh all the time.

It's not black and white, and you have to judge every time if it's worth it, if it's your place to say something and if anybody benefits from you saying it.

Compare it too remarks about looks. You'd tell a friend he should wear another color, you'd tell a colleague that his sweater is inside out, you'd tell a stranger on the elevator that a label is sticking out, but internet remarks about how Britney looks nowadays are completely useless.