# Submit papers without the affiliation to any university/research center

Tags: paper-submission, affiliation

Recently I moved from university (3y Ph.D. and 6y PostDoc position in Information Engineering) to a teacher position in a high school in Italy (sad destiny due to the Education Ministry Gelmini under Berlusconi's premiership).

I'm wondering if I can still submit papers to scientific journals, and if so, I'm also wondering if the current affiliation (high school) is acceptable for journal policies.

Comment: @Anyon thanks for this link!

Comment: There is also the question [Do journals in general have any kind of policy regarding papers submitted by someone without a research affiliation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/385/17254). You may be particularly interested [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/17177/17254), which reports a rejection that seems to be based on a complete lack of affiliation. While I think that is **very** rare, it appears to be at least a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can submit papers. You don't need any affiliation at all, and consider that if the school you are at doesn't have a way to support your research. You can be an "Independent Researcher" for purposes of publication. If you need to attach an email address, make it a relatively permanent one

But a high school is also valid. Most reviewers (I can't promise all) will take the paper on its merits, not your affiliation.

Comment: Thanks a lot (+1). I'm sure reviewers are fair as I am. My doubt is just about journals policies. 

As you say, may I also provide no affiliation? May I provide a personal email address? Again, these questions are related to journals policies, not to reviewers point of view.

Comment: Journal policies won't get in your way. Yes, a personal email is fine. You might need to chat with an editor in a few places, but there are lots of independent researchers, including retired faculty.

Comment: ok, got it. Thanks again!